# Can I use SASS/SCSS variables to set class names?

Tags: sass

I'm trying to create a bunch of columns for a grid layout, and wondering if I can automate the width calculations with a SASS/SCSS mixin.

I'm currently writing

```
@mixin setWidth($a, $b){
 width : ($a / $b)*100%;
}
.col-1-2{
 @include setWidth(1, 2);
}
```

That's fine, but I'm just wondering if there's a way to make it even more DRY, by setting the class with a variable name and creating the class with a mixin.

Something like

```
@mixin setClass($a, $b){
  .col-$a-$b{
    width : ($a / $b)*100%;
  }
}

@include setClass(1, 2);
```

Comment: Tried it, doesn't work. (I didn't expect it to anyway because the syntax doesn't look right, but I'm not really sure what it should be.)

Comment: And what was the error?

Comment: Invalid CSS after " .col-": expected "{", was "$a-$b{"

Comment: You can use them pretty much everywhere including property name. https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/scss/foundation/components/_grid.scss

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to interpolate the variables `#{$a}`when they are being used for naming conventions

```
@mixin setClass($a, $b){
  .col-#{$a}-#{$b} {
    width : ($a / $b)*100%;
  }
}

@include setClass(1, 2);
```

An example : http://sassmeister.com/gist/8634660fa4b32f50b4c1